# A link to open a specific section in the app(android and ios)

Tags: android, ios

Lets say you have already installed the app on your mobile device. That app has many sections. For example, Clothes section, Perfumes section and so on. Is it possible to create a link and whenever you click on it from your device open a targeted section on the app? For instance a shared link on Instagram or Twitter http:/www...etc to open the clothes section dircetly (not only open the app).

Thanks in advance for your replys

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that for iOS 9 by using [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)